# What is a sound manifest?

Tags: gameaudio, procedure, deliveries

This may be a very basic question, but in regards to game sound, I understand there's a "sound manifest" file that is to be delivered for different sequences. To me it sounds like simply a list of all the assets that are used for a particular level or stage. New bad guys, new weapons, new world = new sounds. Am I correct in this? If so, is the manifest simply a .txt file that lists these sound files and their file path location, or is it something that's written in code in order to load these files into the sound engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been asked for a sound manifest before. I've certainly created asset lists that encompass what you're thinking the manifest is. Have you been asked for this by name from a specific company? It could just be the term they use.

In the big picture game audio is still very young and there's areas where terms differ greatly between companies.

Comment: Turns out an asset list is exactly what they're asking for, they simply call it something different. Crazy Canadians...

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across this before - and have never had to deliver a list of sound effects for a scene. I do have assets list and list of potential assets to be used in a scene, but this is more for a internal audio communication than anything that needs delivering anywhere.
One thing that does spring to mind it could be something a publisher would request as part of the console certification process. It is not required for the cert. process itself, but i seem to remember having to do something like this at some stage years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea <- Best answer

Comment: Haha. Sorry, I really had no idea but took my time to Google it. Came up empty or only vague explanations.